# set name of table with variables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a table with a fixed prefix and a variable, something similar as below.

```
set @id=10;
CREATE TABLE Exam_@id(
    name varchar(25) not null,
    roll int(11) not null
    )
```

But mysql throws some error. can any one suggest me the right way to do?*(I am working in phpmyadmin directly).*

-thanks

Comment: or refactor `select .. from exam where exam_id=10`

Comment: What is the error that it throws?

Comment: the error message is  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@id(
    name varchar(2) not null
    )' at line 1